# vertical and horizontal recursion in a tree

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I have a tree data structure in Haskell:

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int [MultTree b] deriving (Show)
```

The task is, to return the hightest number of branches that exists in a tree (so the cardinality of the longest list of an `IndexNode`).

To achieve that I have written a function:

```
grad :: MultTree t -> Int
grad DataNode _       = 0
grad IndexNode _ _ [] = 0
grad IndexNode _ _ (x:xs)
              | isIndexNodeCheck x = max ((countList (x:xs)) (grad x))
```

**Question:** How can I achieve that the function does not only dive deeper in the tree levels but also checks the next element of `xs` ? 
If a write another guard the code will be not run because Haskell always takes the first pattern that matches.

So currently the function should work for vertical recursion but I would like to need to know how to do it also horizontally.

Here is my complete code:

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int [MultTree b] deriving (Show)

t2 :: MultTree Int
t2 = IndexNode 3 42 [IndexNode 7 8 [DataNode 3, DataNode 5, DataNode 7], DataNode 6, IndexNode 10 23 [DataNode 99, DataNode 78, DataNode 24]]

countList :: [a] -> Int
countList [] = 0
countList (x:xs) = 1 + countList xs

isIndexNodeCheck :: MultTree a -> Bool
isIndexNodeCheck (DataNode _) = False
isIndexNodeCheck (IndexNode _ _ _) = True

grad :: MultTree t -> Int
grad DataNode _       = 0
grad IndexNode _ _ [] = 0
grad IndexNode _ _ (x:xs)
              | isIndexNodeCheck x = max ((countList (x:xs)) (grad x))
```

Comment: Read about DFS and BFS.

Comment: How is that helpful advice? We're not searching anything, but rather traversing, and whether we do it breadth-first or depth-first doesn't make a correctness difference.

Comment: @amalloy DFS = "vertical recursion". BFS="horizontal". So it is helpful at least to have the correct terminology. And BFS is what I believe the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: @amalloy  Perhaps, if you find the "search" misleading here, the formally correct names would be "level-order traversal" for BFS, and "post/pre/in-order" traversal for DFS. But I think these terms even being more correct are much less commonly used and more confusing.

Comment: If you read the code OP has written for what he thinks "vertical recursion" is, it's clear that it does not mean DFS, because currently the implementation might better be called a "depth-only" search, where the code only explores the leftmost branch. The OP is asking how to search all the branches of a tree *at all*, not what order is best to explore them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for getting the maximum branching factor:

```
grad :: MultTree a -> Int
grad (DataNode _) = 0
grad (IndexNode _ _ subtrees) =
  -- take the maximum of this tree and of the 
  -- maximum branching factor of all subtrees
  maximum (length subtrees : map grad subtrees)
```

The key is that I get the `grad` of each subtree using `map`.